# Mat Table paginator doesnot works when loading data from a service

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to show a MatTable which populated from a service.

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

displayedUserColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name'];
users: User[] = [];
userDataSource:MatTableDataSource<User>;
errorMessage: string;

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
constructor(private userService: UserService) {

}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe({
  next: (user) => {
    this.users = user;
    this.userDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
  },
  error: (err) => (this.errorMessage = err),
});
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.userDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

The Table Populate properly but it shows the entire list instead of first 5. The paginator doesn't work.

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="userDataSource">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedUserColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedUserColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
      <mat-paginator  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

result looks like this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to move `this.userDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` line after `this.userDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);` line?

Comment: @WalterLuszczyk yes then the result is different , Instead of all the element it loads only first 5 but paginator still behaves the same.

Comment: what about addinh `[pageSize]="5"` param?

Comment: it has no effect

Comment: could you colsole.log() `this.paginator` object before assignment? Is `ViewChild` working correctly? Which version of Angular do you use?

Comment: angular version: 11.0.9, I have used console.log() there are no errors I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is how you are setting the data in the HTTP request.

Try doing this:

```
constructor() {
  this.userDataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userService.getUsers().subscribe({
    next: (user) => {
      this.users = user;
      this.userDataSource.data = this.users;
    },
    error: (err) => (this.errorMessage = err),
  });
}
```

The rest of the code seems to be ok.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: this.userDataSource.data the enitre list empty and in the console I see an error "data.slice is not a function"

Comment: Ok, can you provide the component in https://stackblitz.com/ ?
About the user.service you can mock it with rxjs using `of` and `delay`

Comment: OK I never used stackblitz, but I try to provide you the component soon.

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: ok at last i have finished https://angular-ivy-8yfbtu.stackblitz.io

Comment: you need write the `this.userDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` after assing the MatDataSource -**inside** the subcribe. NOTE: to give one link to a stackblitz simply copy the url in navigator, else we only can see the result

Comment: sorry for the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8yfbtu

Comment: Thanks for the stackblitz link, there I found the issue.
The solution is doing: `this.userDataSource.data = this.users;`

There I updated my answer.

I also, added my solution here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ghimy , you can see that I added a button that reduce the size of the array by 10